# Minimize the maximum component of a sum of vectors

Tags: optimization, vectors, algorithms, discrete-optimization

Given a set of sets of vectors $V=\{V_1=\{v_{11},v_{12},..,v_{1n}\},...,V_m\{v_{m1},v_{m2},..,v_{mn}\}\}$,$v_{ij} \in\{-1,0,1\}^r$. We choose one vector from each set, so that the maximum component of their sum is minimal. Can you advise on how best to approximate the optimal solution of the problem?

UPD:  I'm interested in case m=256,n=65536,r=256.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem via mixed integer linear programming as follows.  Let binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$ indicate whether vector $v_{i,j}$ is chosen, and let $z$ represent the maximum component of the sum of the chosen vectors.  The problem is to minimize $z$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^n x_{i,j} &= 1 &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$} \tag1 \\
\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n (v_{i,j})_k x_{i,j} &\le z &&\text{for $k\in\{1,\dots,r\}$} \tag2
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ chooses one vector from each set.
Constraint $(2)$ enforces the min-max objective.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, linear programming in this case requires too many resources. I'm interested in case m=256,n=65536,r=256.  I have not seen software tools capable of solving such large systems of equations.

Comment: If you have data, I'll try it out.